# Whats the best way to handle finding items in a list that occured after another?

Tags: c#, collections, .net-2.0

I have a class like this

```
public class HistoryEntry
{
    DateTime Date{ get; protected set; }
    HistoryType EntryType { get; protected set; }
}

public enum HistoryType
{
    Cancelled,
    Cleared,
    Redeemed,
    Refunded
}
```

I have an unordered list of these History Entries, and I do Exists statements to see if an entry exists in the list.

```
return Entries.Exists(e => e.EntryType == HistoryEntryType.Cancelled);
```

Now I need to change this so that this method returns whether or not a Cancelled entry exists after the TimeStamp of the **last** Cleared entry if one exists, otherwise just return whether a Cancelled entry exists at all.

I'm limited to options available in .Net 2.0

Comment: Weren't lambda functions introduced in 3.5?

Comment: I think you mean:
    public EntryType { get; protected set; }

Comment: No, lambda expressions were introduced in C# _language specification_ 3.0. They are perfectly usable on framework 2.0.

Comment: @Robert Venables:You mean to say they were added to the Microsoft C# compiler in 2.0?

Comment: No, they were added to the language specification 3.0  - and any compiler that implements that specification, such as the one included in Visual Studio 2008. See: http://download.microsoft.com/download/3/8/8/388e7205-bc10-4226-b2a8-75351c669b09/csharp%20language%20specification.doc The important thing to note is that _Lambda expressions are a language feature_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
    private bool ContainsCanceled(List<HistoryEntry> list)
    {
        list.Sort();
        int index = list.FindLastIndex(delegate(HistoryEntry h) { return h.HistoryType == HistoryType.Cleared; });
        for (int i = index >= 0? index : 0; i < list.Count; i++)
        {
            if (list[i].HistoryType == HistoryType.Cancelled)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return list.Exists(delegate(HistoryEntry h) { return h.HistoryType == HistoryType.Cancelled; });
    }
```

I'm using C#2.0 syntax...

Oh and one more thing, make sure your HistoryEntry class implements IComparable:

```
public class HistoryEntry : IComparable<HistoryEntry>
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public HistoryType HistoryType { get; set; }

    public int CompareTo(HistoryEntry other)
    {
        return this.Date.CompareTo(other.Date);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, works great, but I think theres an error in the logic. If an index is found, and nothing occurs after it in the list that matches the comparison, it'll hit the return list.Exists() statement. I changed it to check for the existence of a Clear entry first, and if one doesn't exist return the list.Exists or continue to the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Search for the index of the matching entries in the list, which requires two searches.

```
int p = Entries.FindIndex(e => e.EntryType == HistoryEntryType.Cleared);
if (p < 0)
    p = 0;
p = Entries.FindIndex(p, e => e.EntryType == HistoryEntryType.Cancelled);
return (p >= 0);
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/efasdh0s.aspx.

Comment: Doesn't that assume the list is in descending order by the DateTime property?

Comment: Yes. The original post was not clear about how the list was ordered.